# Ruby: Alias unexpectedly points to parent class implementation of the aliased method?

Tags: ruby

I have the following Ruby code that features an `alias` in a child class of a method that's defined in the superclass, and overridden in the child class:

```
class Parent
  def hello
    print "Hello, I'm Parent!"
  end
end

class Child < Parent
  alias greet hello
  def hello
    print "Hi, I'm Child!"
  end
end
```

When I call the `greet` alias on an instance of `Child`, it calls the `Parent` implementation of `hello`, not its own class's implementation.  For example, with the above code loaded in irb:

```
2.3.3 :001 > child = Child.new
 => #<Child:0x007fb1118a8f58> 
2.3.3 :002 > child.hello
Hi, I'm Child! => nil 
2.3.3 :003 > child.greet
Hello, I'm Parent! => nil 
2.3.3 :004 >
```

How can I get the alias to point to the local implementation of the method instead of the parent class implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `alias` needs to be located *after* the method to be aliased, not before.

This revised code for the Child class will have `greet` aliased to the local implementation of `hello`, as intended:

```
class Child < Parent
  def hello
    print "Hi, I'm Child!"
  end
  alias greet hello
end
```